# How to Call "help()" for this Object in Plotly?

Tags: python, object, plotly

I am tying to learn using a data visualization tool called *Plotly*. And I am wondering how can I run `help()` on some of the objects attributes to get more information.

I want to use the `go.Box` class that is part of `plotly.graph_objs.graph_objs` module to create a graph, but I do not have much information about the `go.Box` objects and attributes.

I tried using `help(go.Box)`, but it is only giving me minimal information

```
Init signature: go.Box(self, *args, **kwargs)
Docstring:     
Valid attributes for 'box' at path [] under parents ():

['jitter', 'orientation', 'stream', 'ysrc', 'xsrc', 'visible', 'marker',
'y0', 'pointpos', 'line', 'uid', 'showlegend', 'boxmean', 'xaxis',
'type', 'opacity', 'legendgroup', 'fillcolor', 'hoverinfo', 'x0',
'whiskerwidth', 'name', 'yaxis', 'y', 'x', 'boxpoints']

Run `<box-object>.help('attribute')` on any of the above.
'<box-object>' is the object at []
File:           c:\python27\lib\site-packages\plotly\graph_objs\graph_objs.py
Type:           type
```

**Question:** How can I get more information about the `name` attribute of `go.Box`?  How can I run the `<box-object>.help('attribute')` shown above?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I dont have Plotty, but in general you can obtain docstring using [pydoc](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/pydoc.html)

For example, in your case, I would try the following:

```
import pydoc
help_s = pydoc.render_doc(go.Box)
print(help_s)
```